# How to email alert team when app gets published in Google play?

Tags: android, email, gitlab, google-play, alert

Since Google play will take few hours to finish testing and make it live, I am looking for a way to email alert my team members once the process is complete. I couldn't find any solution so far.

We use gitlab as well. So, if any email alert tool exists, when master branch is updated will also work. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add your team in developer account users & manage permissions and they will get email invitation and they will need to accept and afterwards enable app updates notifications. You can look at detailed process here for adding users on play console:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2528691?hl=en

Comment: This answer is miss leading: those email does not exist for app publishing approval, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77044498/2127277

Answer (score 1):

If you go to your Play Console's preferences, you should be able to activate an email option that will allow you to receive emails as soon as your production app has been published.

Screenshot of the option:

[image: Email option]

Comment: Yes, i know that. I want the alert to go to a list of users, say to everybody in the Android team.

Comment: This answer is miss leading: those email does not exist for app publishing approval, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77044498/2127277